# Запомнить место конца анимации

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте! Как запомнить положении в котором остался элемент? Ну допустим он повернулся на 260º и мне надо запомнить чтобы потом продолжить анимку с этого места.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById("h").classList.add("anim");
};

document.getElementById("no").onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById("h").classList.remove("anim");
};
```

```css
@keyframes wheely {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  to {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
@-webkit-keyframes wheely{
  from {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  to {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}

.anim {animation: wheely 5s linear infinite;}
```

```html
<div id="h">133722848</div>
<button id="btn">анимка</button>
<button id="no">нет</button>
```

Comment: можно на js реализовать?

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy Естественно, а как еще :) По другому не получится.

Comment: я про кейфреймы

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy Ну нормально. Хоть на JS хоть на CSS – разницы нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var rotate = 0;
var startRotating;
document.getElementById("h").style.transform = 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)';

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
  var target = document.getElementById("h");
  startRotating = setInterval(rotatefunc, 10, target);
};

document.getElementById("no").onclick = function(){
  clearInterval(startRotating);
};

function rotatefunc(target) {
  rotate++;
  target.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)';
}
```

```css
#h {
  transform: rotate(200deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="h">133722848</div>
<button id="btn">анимка</button>
<button id="no">нет</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает отлично!

Comment: незачто, рад помочь

Comment: Хотел еще спросить: как надо изменить код если `target` будет массивом и надо анимировать 2 элемента?

Comment: несколько блоков  id 'h'?

Comment: Да только уже с классом `h`

Comment: var target = objects[1];

Comment: Я имею в виду куда цикл для перебора написать.

Comment: в самом начале можно перебрать елементы и записать их в массив objects